# Reason of inductive kick

Tags: inductor

Suppose an Ideal voltage source is connected with an RL circuit all components in series for a long time.

Suddenly switch is opened and the inductor will built across it the voltage which will make the current to flow in the same  direction in which the current was already flowing.

My question is why this happens?

What I think is that when the current was flowing energy was stored in inductor in the form of  magnetic field. When switch is opened the magnetic field around the inductor collapse and it induces the voltage in the direction such that the current may continue to flow in the same direction as it was flowing when the switched was not opened (Lenz Law).

Am i true in my thinking or there is anyother reason for this inductive kick of the inductor?

Comment: The energy for the kick does come from the collapsing magnetic field and the draining of that energy is why the magnetic field collapses.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  The collapsing magnetic field is what provides the energy to the inductive kick.

Comment: The collapsing magnetic field induces the voltage. A collapsing magnetic field doesn't provide energy however (in case you meant to say this), the duration of the collapse is the duration it takes for energy to fully deplete. Now matter how long or slowly the field collapses, it's the same energy.

Comment: @Andyaka Isn't that the same thing? You draw energy from the magnetic field for the kick and the lack of energy causes the magnetic field to collapse. The energy certainly isn't coming from nowhere.

Comment: \$V = -N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ hence the faster the magnetic field collapses, the bigger the voltage. The energy is related to what current the inductor was taking prior to it going open circuit @DKNguyen

Comment: Yes, good clarification.  "Collapse" is the d/dt part that determines the voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka That's the same thing though since the current that was going through the inductor prior to the kick is also the energy stored in the magnetic field. No one is talking about the size of the kick or the time of the collapse. That's a matter of power. The energy is the energy regardless of the time over which it dissipates. Could it be that when you talk about "kick" you are referring solely to the initial voltage spike? When I say kick I am referring to the overall behaviour of the inductor pushing current in the absence of external power.

Comment: Higher V for the same current pushed naturally means higher power which naturally means the magnetic field collapses faster because you are drawing energy from it faster.

Comment: @Andy aka. What determines how fast the magnetic field will collapse?

Comment: @Alex The lowest impedance path available for the current to loop around and circulate through the inductor. An airgap (or open mechanical switch) is high impedance, so high voltage, more power, faster collapse. That's what the arc is. Snubbers and flyback diodes are low impedance so lower voltage, lower power, slower collapse. Simplest case is resistive path and the L/R time constant. Lower R = longer time constant.

Comment: @alex - basically how quickly the spark or kickback voltage dissipates the energy